# HTML - Only some anchor links working (same page)

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm using anchor links to link to headers on the same page. But only some work. This is my code:

```
<ol type="A">
    <li>
        <a href="#HandleidingWebsite">Handleiding Website</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#Inleiding">Inleiding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Hoofdscherm">Hoofdscherm / Rooster</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Input">Input</a>
                <ol type="a">
                    <li><a href="#Machinerooster">Machinerooster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Ploegenrooster">Ploegenrooster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Beschikbaarheid">Beschikbaarheid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#SkillMatrix">Skill Matrix</a></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Afdelingen">Afdelingen</a></li>
...
```

It links to the following div's:

```
<h1 id="HandleidingWebsite">A. Handleiding Website</h1>
<hr />
<div class="handleidingH2" id="Inleiding">
    <h2>1. Inleiding</h2>
</div>
...
<br />
<div class="handleidingH2" id="Afdelingen">
    <h2>5. Afdelingen</h2>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="Machinerooster" class="handleidingH3">
    <h2>Machinerooster</h2>
</div>
```

These links work:

- Inleiding
- Login
- Hoofdscherm
- Input
- Inleiding

But linking to #Machinerooster or #Afdelingen doesn't work. The URL changes, but the scroll position stays the same.

I have seen solutions on Stackoverflow about a `<base>` tag, but i don't have a `<base>` tag.

I'm using Firefox, but i have the same problem on all browsers. First I thought the problem might be the length of the page, but pasting it to another position doesn't help.

The div's I want to link to are not nested in other elements. I have no duplicate ID's.

I have no clue what the problem could be, I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Can you please show a full example (preferably a live one)? Do you have any additional JavaScript code running in that page, that might interfere in some way?

Comment: @CBroe I have a scroll to top button. It doens't use an anchor link. 'document.body.scrollTop = 0; document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;'

Comment: Can you give us the full html please? It would help !

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yAK7LVcK This is the code. Page is not done yet, but syntax should be right. EDIT: https://pastebin.com/0P5t9ESf <-- this is the _Layout file.

Comment: In the code you gave us #Machinerooster is working and #Afdelingen has no id linked to. Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/9bap4xow/

Comment: Oh uploaded a new version, but in my code it has a link. Your fiddle works for me on the #machinerooster link, but on my website it does not work, with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in my _Layout file. I used the same ID's in the navigation menu. So the problem was duplicate ID's.